# How differentiable must an integral be?

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, integration

Let $f : \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ be Riemann-integrable and let $F : \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ be defined $F(x) = \int_0^x f(x)\, dx$.

How differentiable must $F$ be? It is easy to construct examples where $F$ is not differentiable on a countably infinite set, take $f$ to be the floor function, for example. On the other end, $F$ cannot fail to be differentiable on a set with non-zero measure, due to the Lesbegue criterion for Riemann integrability.

But can $F$ fail to be differentiable

- on an uncountably infinite set, like the Cantor set?
- on a set with non-zero measure, if we use Lesbegue integration?
- on a set with full measure, if we use Lesbegue integration?
- everywhere, if we use Lesbegue integration?

Comment: Using the Lebesgue integral, $F$ is absolutely continuous and differentiable almost everywhere.  Look up FTC for Lebesgue integrals.

Comment: Adding to RRL's comment, it suffices for $f$ to be absolutely integrable (w.r.t. Lebesgue integration). $F$ will be differentiable almost everywhere with derivative $f$.

Comment: What if $f$ is the Cantor function ... https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cantor_function  Will $F$ then fail to be differentiable on an uncountable set?

Comment: @GEdgar The Cantor function is continuous so $F$ is easily differentiable everywhere. Maybe you were thinking about a function whose set of discontinuities is the Cantor set?